# Leap Motion V3 (Orion) returning points whose value is infinity

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I'm getting Leap frames with a bunch of points whose value is `infinity` within them. Is this normal for `V3 (Orion)`, or am I doing something wrong? I noticed this wasn't happening in `V2` of `Leap Motion`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You used this code for getting position?

```
Vector position = hand.PalmPosition;
```